# Random walk: How to exit a for loop properly

Tags: matlab

Given the following random walk script

```
 1      f = zeros(1,100);
 2      x = 40;
 3      for i = 1:1000
 4          r = rand;
 5          if r >= 0.5
 6              x = x + 1;
 7          else
 8              x=x-1;
 9          end
10          if x ~= 0 | x ~= 100
11              f(x) = f(x) + 1;
12          elseif x==0 | x==100
13              break
14          end
15      end
16      bar(f)
```

Sometimes, it gives me the following error:

```
Array indices must be positive integers or logical values.

Error in random_walk (line 11)
        f(x) = f(x) + 1;
```

Which is normal since `x=0`. **But why isn't the `elseif` condition not satisfied to execute `break` and avoid this error?**

Comment: Your `if` condition needs an `&` instead of `|`. `elseif` is fine.

Comment: Its much easier (and bug free)  to do `if(x==0 | x==100); break; else; f(x) = f(x) + 1; end`

Answer (score 3):

`if x ~= 0 | x ~= 100` can never be false. If `x~=0` is false, then `x~=100` will be true. One of the two components is always true, and hence the OR combination is always true.

You might want to use `if x ~= 0 && x ~= 100` instead.

Do note the difference between `|` and `||`, and between `&` and `&&`. The single operator is an element-wise operator, and potentially returns a matrix. The other one is a true Boolean operator that always returns a simple `true` or `false`. In this particular case the two are identical, but it is good habit to use use the right operator in the right location.

Note also that the following `elseif` should be a plain `else`. You should never repeat yourself, that only leads to hard-to-find bugs.